# IE (10) Does not render Box shadow well on inputs

Tags: internet-explorer-10, css

I created the following jsbin to show the problem. http://jsbin.com/fewuli/2/ If you run this in any browser but IE10 and focus the input then the box shadow outline looks great like this:

[image]

But if you run this in IE10 (or IE9+) it doesnt render the top portion of the box shadow on focus like this:
[image]

Is there any way to fix this without increasing the box shadow size (last option?)

Answer (score 0):

I tested the link you provided and checked it out in different versions of IE (11, 10 and 9) and they all showed the input box being highlighted when it held the focus. (I used the IE toolbar Emulation to view the differences)

If you are still having problems with this you could try adding a script that helps older IE browsers support HTML5. [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/#html5inie) is one of these scripts that will help in this way. There is also [HTML5 Shiv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Shiv) but that only supports IE browsers 9 and older.

Another suggestion would be to try MS Visual Filters and Transitions and apply it to your INPUT class:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30);
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30)";
```

Comment: Added some more screen shots. I don't think Modernzr would help here.

Comment: Updated my answer with some other suggestions to address the IE issue.

Comment: Hey @Tim did you see the edit to my answer? Any luck on getting this to work?

Comment: Yeah i ended up using the four value syntax which changes the output but it leas shows more solid in IE.
 
 box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px #0095ff;